# How to get text after link in htmlagilitypack

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html-agility-pack

I have next part of html code:

```
<div class="resum_card">
  <p><a href="#opyt" class="no_decore">Experience:</a> 5 years</p>
</div>
```

And what i try inside the code:

```
nodeValue = hd.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='resum_card']//p//a[@class='no_decore']//following-sibling::a");
```

But it return me null, can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this XPath to get text node after `<a>` element :

```
nodeValue = hd.DocumentNode
              .SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='resum_card']/p/a/following-sibling::text()");
```

Note: simply use single slash (`/`) instead of double (`//`) to select element that is direct child of current element. It is better performance wise.